# Problema com TimeZone do JSF

Tags: jsf-2.2

Esse é meu método no managerBean

```
public void carregarDadosVenda(){
    vendaCadastro.setHorario(new Date());
}
```

essa é minha pagina;

```
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText id="txtVendaValorTotal"
            value="Valor Total: #{carrinhoComprasBean.vendaCadastro.valor} " />
        <p:commandButton value="Finalizar Venda"
            action="#{carrinhoComprasBean.carregarDadosVenda}"
            oncomplete="PF('wvDlgFinVenda').show();" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>

<p:dialog closable="true" draggable="true" modal="true"
    resizable="false" header="Dados da Venda" widgetVar="wvDlgFinVenda"
    appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Horário " />
            <h:outputText value="#{carrinhoComprasBean.vendaCadastro.horario}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>                   
            </h:outputText>
            <h:outputText value="Nome da Noticia " />
            <h:outputText  />
            <h:outputText value="Valor Toral " />
            <h:outputText />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar: " />
            <p:commandButton value="Voltar: "
                onclick="PF('wvDlgFinVenda').hide();" />
        </p:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
```

E coloquei isso no arquivo web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

porque será que mesmo assim não aparece a data na minha caixa de mensagem?

Eu printei o valor assim;

```
public void carregarDadosVenda(){

        vendaCadastro.setHorario(new Date());
    System.out.println("Horário >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"  + vendaCadastro.getHorario());   
    }
```

E tive esse resultado aqui;

Horário >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Mon Aug 31 14:59:05 BRT 2015

=======================================================================

Aconteceu algo mais estranho ainda;

eu resolvi refazer o código tudo de novo, e com isso voltou a funcionar, porém o horário estava errado, e eu queria sincronizar o horário com o servidor TomCat, e coloquei essa linha de código no web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Depois que fiz isso não aparece mais o horário na caixa de dialog, eu até excluir na linha de código do arquivo web.xml, mas não teve jeito, o horário não aparece mais na caixa de dialog.

porque será que isso acontece?

Comment: Você já printou no console essa data?

Comment: acabei de atualizar minha postagem, dê uma olhada por favor.

Comment: atualizei mais uma vez a minha postagem, dá uma olhada por favor.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você quer exibir uma data formatada em um campo texto?

Comment: positivo, porque tem algum problema?

Comment: Você teria alguma boa sugestão?

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
<h:outputText value="#{var.data}">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="GMT-3" />
</h:outputText>
```